# Match Pattern based on multiple special characters

Tags: python, regex

Regex to match more than one special characters after a string

I am trying to come up with regex to match in the order of importance as below

1. String plus 2 or more special characters followed by some word
2. String plus 1 special character followed by some word
3. String (and no special characters) followed by some word

I am able to match all patterns with below regex

```
re.compile(r'keyword\W*\s*(\S*)', re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
```

but it does not differentiate between different scenarios after keyword.

for example:
considering keyword is the string above

If I have string 'keyword-+blah' I should be able to match with 1 only

if I have string 'keyword-blah' I should be able to match with 2 only

if I have String 'keywordblah' I should be able to match with 3 only

Comment: Perhaps use a character class with a quantifier `keyword[+-]{0,2}\w+` https://regex101.com/r/98W5V0/1

Answer (score 2):

You could use a character class to specify which chars you consider to be special. Then use a quantifier `{0,2}` to match a repetition of 0, 1 or 2 times.

The following `\w+` matches 1+ times a word character.

Note that `\S` matches a non whitespace char so that would also match `-` or `+`

```
keyword[+-]{0,2}\w+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/98W5V0/1/)